# Print all keyword in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a script to delete many files, but it is a very extensive command to process for Linux, for this I have decided to remove with "rm -rf key*" but first I can not find how to create this function that prints all the aetas from A to Z

If I can create a cycle I will be able to complete the task and continue in the construction of my Script.

Comment: Can you expand on what your series of keys look like?  Is it simply keya, keyb, etc.?  Or?

Comment: If you just want to delete all files, `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 rm -f` will run `rm -f` as many as times as necessary to get the whole set. Same for `key*` if you want to prefix. Similarly, `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'key*' -exec rm -f -- '{}' +` will do the trick.

Comment: ...which is to say, if we assume your problem here is that you're trying to avoid errors because the command-line length is exceeding your operating system's maximum, there are better ways to work around it, and you should ask about that underlying problem, not about your attempted workaround for it.

Comment: I need print: a b c d e f ... to aplply my "for cycle"

Comment: You need that *why*? What's the problem you're trying to solve? (Specifically, is that larger problem max command line length?)

Comment: If you're just looking to get a series of keys (like a, b, c, d, etc.) you can do so with:
`echo {a..f}`

Comment: ...but for the general case, that's a lousy solution. For one, it *won't actually cover all possible filenames* -- files can start with names not included in the range from `a` to `z`. Filenames can contain characters that aren't even *printable* at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what it is you are looking for but I once had a shell script that did like:

```
ns="/path/to/file.extension,/path/to/directory,/path/to/something*";
IFS=',';
read -a path <<< "${ns}";
nr="${#path[@]}";
start="0";

for (( i = ${start}; i <=${nr}; i++ )); do
    echo "Starting fast-delete round $i of $nr, deleting ${path[$i]}";
    rm -rf ${path[$i]};
    echo "Done with round $i, deleted ${path[$i]}";
done;
```

You can extend upon the ns list as much as you'd like, and it also allows for the use of asterix-characters as a wildcard. So `/path/to/*` matches all files and folders in `/path/to`. Be careful though, as it is pretty unforgiving if you make any errors in the specified paths. So you could easily end up deleting more then you bargained for.

**RISK IS YOURS** (should mention that to be sure)

PS: I since created a GUI-python script that allows for much more fine-tuning. It's a nice challenge if you are trying to learn to code.

**EDIT** (see comments):

Judging by your comment, do you mean something like this?

```
for x in {a..z}
do
    rm -rf /home*/${x}*/mail/*/*/.Trash/cur/*
done
```

This will execute:

`rm -rf /home*/a*/mail/*/*/.Trash/cur/*`, `rm -rf /home*/b*/mail/*/*/.Trash/cur/*`, etc, etc.

Comment: Ok, i need run this command: 

rm -rf /home*/*/mail/*/*/.Trash/cur/* 

I need make a cicle for remplace: /home*/a*,b*,c* ....

Comment: Edited my answer (see EDIT), still isn't exactly clear what you are asking though..